# Arranging 15 acrobats in a specified order

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> There are $15$ acrobats who want to take acrobatics classes. Each of the $15$ acrobats are of different skill level. Assume acrobat $1$ has skill level equal to $1$, acrobat $2$ has $2$ skill level equal to $2$, and so on. There are $20$ different acrobatics classes, each with different difficulty. Multiple acrobats may take the same classes. Each acrobat is only permitted to take one $1$ class, but when acrobat $1$ picks a
>   course, acrobat $2$ must take a course at least as difficult. This
>   continues with acrobat $3$ and so on. In general, an acrobat with skill level $x$ must take a course at least as difficult as the acrobats with less skill level. How many ways can you assign the $15$ acrobats to their courses?

I tried to solve the problem with casework but it gets really messy. Maybe someone can help me. I think acrobat $1$ needs to choose one of the first $5$ courses. Then, depending on that choice, acrobat $2$ has to pick a different number of courses, etc.

I also tried to write a computer program with it, but it got really messy as well. I am sure there is some clever trick to this. Maybe someone can help me figure it out.

One last idea I had was to work backwards (place the acrobat with highest skill level first, and so on). This doesn't really seem to work either.

Comment: Starting backwards is my first thought too. If $a_1$ starts in the highest skill level there is only one possibility. If he starts in the second highest, and $a_2$ takes the highest again, then the others again have no other choice. I would follow this trail.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that a particular assignment is completely determined by how many acrobats take each of the classes.  For instance, if we have the distribution
$$(3, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$$
then acrobats 1, 2, and 3 take the least difficult class, acrobat 4 takes the second least difficult class, acrobats 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 take the fourth least difficult class, acrobats 10, 11, and 12 take the ninth least difficult class, acrobats 13 and 14 take the tenth least difficult class, and acrobat 15 takes the twelfth least difficult class.

Thus, what we seek is the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + \cdots + x_{15} + x_{16} + x_{17} + x_{18} + x_{19} + x_{20} = 15$$
in the nonnegative integers, where $x_j$, $1 \leq j \leq 20$, is the number of acrobats taking class $j$.

A particular solution of the equation corresponds to the placement of $20 - 1 = 19$ addition signs in a row of $15$ ones.  For instance, the distribution in the example above is represented by
$$1 1 1 + 1 + + 1 1 1 1 1 + + + + + 1 1 1 + 1 1 + + 1 + + + + + + + +$$
The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can insert $19$ addition signs into a row of $15$ ones, which is 
$$\binom{15 + 20 - 1}{20 - 1} = \binom{34}{19}$$ 
since we must choose which $19$ of the $34$ positions required for $15$ ones and $19$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.